# Django cannot serve files after moving to compose

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

#### Context

Hi, we have a big project in Django. Up until now, we have used Vagrant to run it. Now, we have decided to move to a container and use docker compose. Everything has worked out fine except for the serving of static files. We have a directory called `web` where we have all our static assets. Inside there, there are more subdirectories with more static assets.

#### Problem

Right now static files are not being served. Is curious because only some files are being served. I think the ones from the `web` directory are not working for some reason.

#### Current django config

This config has worked well before moving to docker.

```py
# this is necessary because our settings file are stored inside a directoy
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..'))
PUBLIC_DIR = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'public')

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PUBLIC_DIR, 'static')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'web'),
)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)
```

#### Additional information

We are using django-1.11 and python 3.6.9. I know, it's not the latest.

#### Compose configuration

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
    web:
        image: "dev"
        container_name: web
        ports:
            - "8000:8000"
        volumes:
            - ./:/app
        depends_on:
            - db
        networks:
            - djangonetwork
    db:
        image: "postgres"
        container_name: db
        ports:
            - "5432:5432"
        networks:
            - djangonetwork
networks:
  djangonetwork:
      driver: bridge
```

Any idea about what could be the problem?

Comment: The `volumes:` mount overwrites the content in the image with potentially different content from your host system; this can result in files being missing or you running an entirely different application than you expect.  Does deleting the `volumes:` help?

Comment: While checking that (that has not worked) I have discovered that for some reason the variable `debug` in my django templates is set to false. Even if I set it to true in my settings. Pretty weird.